# Need to escape " , ' along with other UNICODE characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, unicode

I have the following string :

```
"ѯѰѱѲ & <b>BOLD</b> <>?:"{}|+_)(*&^%\\\\\\$#@!~`,./;'[]\
```

(with the starting " and the  " in the middle).

I tried the following 3 functions : escape, encodeURI and  encodeURIComponents.

However all three give the error of : `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` obviously due to the presence of starting " closing with the middle ".

I do not want to use regex replace to escape " and ' in the string. Is there any direct JS/jQuery function which would do the same?

```
CODE:
Was earlier doing this : e.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(encodeURIComponent($scope.nameToSearch.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: No i mean a function which would do it on its own?

Comment: Like i do not have to manually esscape.. write a regex as i might miss something or that it would clash with something else

Comment: You'll have to show more of your code. Where is that content coming from? It sounds like that whatever is generating that content should do the escaping.

Comment: I am taking the string from ng-model of angualr.js

Comment: or i could have it hardcoded too .. How does that matter ? My question is that id there a direct method to do so .. Why should the source matter?

Comment: *"am taking the string from ng-model of angualr.js"* If you were, you wouldn't be having a syntax error with it, because it wouldn't be being parsed by the JavaScript engine at that point; it would *already* be a string.

Comment: No it should not. It could be a hardcoded string .. or antything ... i cant pour out my code here .. otherwise it becomes way too long and noone wants to read long questions...The above is my precise query.

Comment: There's a **big** difference between no code and too much code. *"The above is my precise query"* It's not remotely precise.

Comment: I need to escape " and ' without using regex replace. SIMPLE. Kindly do not downvote if you do not get the solution.

Comment: am taking the string from ng-model of angualr.js" If you were, you wouldn't be having a syntax error with it, because it wouldn't be being parsed by the JavaScript engine at that point; it would already be a string. >> Please explian

Comment: @BhumiSinghal: I'm sorry, but you're simply making no sense whatsoever. I suggest reading up on strings and string literals. If the question is being downvoted, it's because it's "unclear or not useful".

Comment: @BhumiSinghal: Re receiving the string from Angular: It's the difference between a *string* and a *string literal*. In any case, I've long since shown you how to get the hardcoded version, which you said you wanted above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Looking at his code $scope.nameToSearch.toLowerCase() 
nameToString is a string instance. So it is indeed hardcoded.  The console would have shown the SyntaxError right where he made that assignment.  
OP, This has nothing to do with *encode*s function. You're writing invalid javascript so you will get SyntaxError

Comment: @cswl: Unless it's coming from the user (which I tend to doubt). Yes, it may be hardcoded *somewhere*; it's not hardcoded *there*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, if the user input was being **eval** ed. I guess... ?
Either way, the console will show where the error was being thrown.  I think this is more of a *I'm too lazy to escape my strings*

Comment: Hi .. " $scope.nameToSearch.toLowerCase() nameToString is a string instance. So it is indeed hardcoded." @cswl : actually it is the ng-model value. Hardcoding was probablity which i mentioned. But NO. In the code it is not hardcoded. It is a ng-model to input type text.

Comment: I guess i would read more about Strings and String Literals to understand how is any of this making any difference.

Comment: @cswl : Can you please explain how does $scope.nameToSearch.toLowerCase()   mean that this is hardcoded in the system ?Since this is a scope var how is it not possible that it is coming from the user?

Comment: @BhumiSignhal Yes, the string in the nameToValue, could have come from anywhere. But as others have pointed, we can only make assumptions given the little code you have provided.  Theres a  difference between copy pasting your entire project, and a smaller instance of your problem. But again if the problem cant be reproduced, how can anyone trying to help you solve it?  
I'm sorry for the remark I made. It wasnt appropriate to make that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

> or i could have it hardcoded too

For the hardcoded version, just put it in quotes with escapes for the quotes and backslashes:

```
// Quotes v                                                                 v
var str = '"ѯѰѱѲ & <b>BOLD</b> <>?:"{}|+_)(*&^%\\\\\\\\\\\\$#@!~`,./;\'[]\\';
// Escapes -------------------------------------^-^-^-^-^-^-----------^---^
```